# Laravel 8 and Multiple Optional Parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing

I want to create a route using Laravel 8 that will allow for a number of multiple and optional parameters. For example, if this route was displaying a list of people, it could be something like any of the following:

- /people
- /people/age/24
- /people/hair/brown/age/30
- /people/status/4

Or if it's easier something like this:

- /people
- /people/age-24
- /people/hair-brown/age-30
- /people/status-4

The parameters are all optional. The order should not matter. If possible I would like to do this without the use of a controller.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Encoded Forward Slashes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-encoded-forward-slashes). Using a `where` condition regular expression (`.*`):

```
# http://myapp.test/people/hair/brown/age/30

Route::get('people/{search?}', function ($search = null) {

    // Your logic here..

    dd($search); // hair/brown/age/30

})->where('search', '.*');
```

If you want to parse `$search` into an array that you might use to query your model, you can use this way:

```
Route::get('people/{search?}', function ($search = null) {

    $search = trim(preg_replace('|/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)|', '$1=$2&', $search), '&');
    parse_str($search, $query);
    $query = array_filter($query); // To prevent elements that have no value

    dd($query);

})->where('search', '.*');
```

- `/people/hair/brown/age/30`
- `/people/hair/brown/age/30/key-with-no-value`

Result :

```
[
  "hair" => "brown",
  "age"  => "24"
]
```

Comment: I also don't recommend that you use the `/people/hair-brown/age-30` format. Because it will be difficult to parse `-` if the key or value has `-`.

Comment: Awesome thanks @WahyuKristianto! I like this better than any solution I found before asking!

Comment: Glad to help you